# How to properly tell Google they have no right to access the download. What status do I use?

Tags: google, web-crawlers, images, http, noindex

I'm looking for the SEO way to tell Google not to download pictures.

I have a script that generates one of two things based on who accesses the site:

If an unauthorized robot accesses the site, they will receive a message that they should visit the website first.

Users on the other hand who have seen the site first will cause the script to generate the picture for them.

I already have this header:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, noimageindex
```

But I'm not too sure what status code I should hand to robots (who receive the message instead of the picture). Right now, I set it to 200 to denote a valid page. I was thinking of setting it to 401, but I don't know if that's correct in this case.

Comment: I used to 301 the bots to a porn site... What??... Not what you are looking for? ;-)

Comment: I'm trying to impress google here

Comment: Cash works for me... the greener the better... I do not have an answer for you, but I will think about it and will let you know if something comes to mind.

Comment: "no right to access the download" - my first thought is a "403 Forbidden".What resource is being requested - that is being blocked? Are you saying the same script serves "a message" when the user is not authorised and a "picture" if they are?

Comment: Yes. That's what I am saying.

Comment: A "picture" as in an `image/jpeg` response, or a "picture" as in a `text/html` (ie. `<img src="...`) response? The way it's written above it sounds like the former (but I don't see how that would work?) and if it's the later then the block/403 should probably be on the image resource itself, not necessarily the page that contains the image?

Comment: The bigger question is *why* are you serving different content to search engines and users?

Comment: I don't want any kind of robot to steal pictures. As for the html, I can understand letting search engines see everything as they need it to index the site.

Comment: Just use 403 (or even 404) if something isn't meant to be accessed, no need to do anything fancy.

Answer (score 1):

> to tell google not to download pictures

If i understand you correctly, you don't want, that images appear in the image search? If yes, then publish such images like [data uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and [they will be not indexed](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/69312/43910).

Answer (score 1):

Blocking the directories with images using robots.txt is one way, but google crawls as a human ne so blocking images etc impacts how google sees your site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not show two different things to bots and users. Instead, just don't allow google image bot to index your site.

You should place this in your robots.txt

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /
```

Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=en