# Does googlebot index base64 encoded images

Tags: seo, google-search, ranking

I was wondering if google can crawl image like this:

`<img src="data:image/png;base64..." title="relevant title" alt="relevant alt" />`

I found this link that says no: [Base64 encoded images and availability of their metadata for Googlebot](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69309/base64-encoded-images-and-availability-of-their-metadata-for-googlebot)

But it's been 6 years since that post, and I was wondering if things had changed. I want to provide the best user experience for my users, but not at the cost of my ranking.

In my case I have more than 3 million pages which all have "small" images that I would like to embed/inline to increase initial performance of page load, but also these images are well ranked on images and search, I don't want to loose that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes directly from Google's [Image Best Practices](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=en) document which I assume is up to date and current.

> ### Supported image formats
>
> Google Images supports images in the following formats: BMP, GIF,
> JPEG, PNG, WebP, and SVG.
>
> You can also inline images as Data URIs. Data URIs provide a way to
> include a file, such as an image, inline by setting the src of an img
> element as a Base64 encoded string using the following format:
>
> ```
> <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]">
> ```
>
> While inlining images can reduce HTTP requests, you should carefully
> judge when to use them since it can considerably increase the size of
> the page. For more on this, refer to the [section on pros and cons of
> inlining images on our Web Fundamentals page](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images#inlining_pros_cons).

Comment: That's good to know